# Can gdb print 64-bit address?

Tags: gdb, memory-address

I entered the following command in gdb:

```
(gdb) p PyObject_GetAttrString($2, "_other_obj_m")
```

and got the following output which should be a variable address type (PyObject*).

```
$4 = -246881136
```

Then I used printf to convert it to hex format and got a wrong address "0xf148e490", the real address is "0x4f78f148e490".
Any one know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target program doesn't have any debugging info for a function, gdb will assume that the function has return type `int`. On x86_64 Linux, that's likely to be 4 bytes.

```
$ gdb -q python2.7
(gdb) ptype PyObject_GetAttrString
type = int ()
(gdb) p sizeof(int)
$1 = 4
```

If your target has debugging info, you'll get the correct result.

```
$ gdb -q python2.7-dbg
Reading symbols from python2.7-dbg...done.
(gdb) ptype PyObject_GetAttrString
type = struct _object {
    struct _object *_ob_next;
    struct _object *_ob_prev;
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
} *(PyObject *, const char *)
```

If you don't have any debugging info, you can cast the function symbol to the correct type signature, or to one that's close enough, such as *pointer to function returning `void *`*. Try this:

```
(gdb) p ((void * (*)(void *, char *))PyObject_GetAttrString)($2, "_other_obj_m")
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkP. Command `(gdb) p ((void * (*)(void *, char *))PyObject_GetAttrString)($2, "_other_obj_m")` get the right answer.

Comment: Some times I can got the right answer by command ` p ((PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, char *))PyObject_GetAttrString)($4, "_other_obj_m")`, but sometimes got  `Segmentation fault` like the following output: